# Can variables be passed through API call to AMPscript block?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript

We are trying to pass through external variables via an API call that will then assign values within an AMPscript block to populate a triggered SMS communication. All the API calls are ending up in the error queue at the moment.Here's what we have in place now:

```
        %%[ 
        Var @HOHID, @ClinicID, @curTime, @CancellationCodeEnglish, @CancellationCodeSpanish
        Set @ClinicID = %%ClinicId%%
        Set @HOHID = %%HOHId%%
        Set @ReasonCode = %%CancellationReasonCode%%
        Set @FriendlyClinicName = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","FacilityName","CRMFacilityID”,@ClinicID)
        Set @CancellationCodeEnglish = Lookup(“Cancellation_Reason_Codes”,"ReasonCode_English","CancellationReasonCode”,@ReasonCode)
        Set @CancellationCodeSpanish = Lookup(“Cancellation_Reason_Codes”,"ReasonCode_Spanish","CancellationReasonCode”,@ReasonCode)
        Set @MsgLanguage = Lookup("b_patient_data","Language","HOHid",@HOHID)

        IF @MsgLanguage == "English"    
        Set @msg = “Your %%[%%= v(@FriendlyClinicName) =%%]%% office is closed due to %%[%%= v(@CancellationCodeEnglish) =%%]%%. Someone will call you to reschedule."
        else
        Set @msg = “Su %%[%%= v(@FriendlyClinicName) =%%]%% está %%[%%= v(@CancellationCodeSpanish) =%%]%%. Alguien le llamará para una nueva cita."
        endif
        ]%%
        %%= v(@msg) =%%
```

Here is the snipped where we are creating the attribute (done in a loop):

```
                subscriber.Attributes[attributeIndex] = new ExactTargetAPI.Attribute();
                subscriber.Attributes[attributeIndex].Name = dc.ColumnName;
                subscriber.Attributes[attributeIndex].Value = subscriberData[dc.ColumnName].ToString();
```

Comment: You have opening and closing script blocks within the main script block, this will error. You will need to remove the %% around ClinicId for example.

Comment: @victorcorey we are using those opening/closing script blocks as the pointer for the API call. THose variables are being passed in externally. Will the API call know to associate the parameter with those removed?

Comment: What is the API call? Here's an example for a Triggered Send API call. The external data is being passed in a parameter called xml. https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/passing_content_to_a_triggered_send_message_at_send_time/

Comment: So I think what you are looking to do is: Set @ClinicID = ClinicId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of updates to make this work:

- Removed the '%%' characters from the set statement
- Removed the 'Your %%[%%= v(@FriendlyClinicName) =%%]%%'... portions and replaced with concat @msg
- The Spanish version would not allow specific characters to be used in mobile (I.E. the accent symbols)